# Input validation does not trigger till I click something on page. How to avoid this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have inputs that I check for empty, null etc. I do this by storing a state boolean and updating it with onChange events for each input. Each input is stored in a session variable using React.useState. The validation work does work, but if I type something in then hit backspace till the input box is empty you can click submit button and send an empty piece of data and I do not know how to prevent this because I'm checking every onChange event for every input box.

Here is one of my inputs

```
<input id="editCourse_placeHolder_courseName" type="text" placeholder={edit_Course?.name} onChange={new_category_name}/>
```

Here is where I validate form input for my state variable

```
const formValidation = ():void => {
        if(state_category_name && state_category_name.trim()){
            state_form_Validation = false;
        } else {
            state_form_Validation = true;
        }
        setState_form_validation(state_form_Validation);
    };
```

here is my state variable that holds the value of the input box which then gets sent to server.

```
let [state_category_name, setState_New_Category_Name] = React.useState<string | undefined>("");
```

State boolean to enable this button if all input is good

```
let [state_form_Validation, setState_form_validation] = React.useState<boolean>(true);

<input name="view" disabled={state_form_Validation} type="submit" onClick={() => {submitEdit();history.push("/");}} value="Edit"/>
```

And my on change event

```
const new_category_name = (e:any):void => {
        setState_New_Category_Name(e.target.value);
        formValidation();
    };
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things wrong here.

First, don't set state variables explicitly, e.g., `myVariable = 'new value'`. Only update them with the setter, e.g., `setMyVariable('new value')`. The setter you get back from the `useState` hook is what ties you into the component lifecycle and will re-render it based on changes.

`onChange` should be a function not a value, e.g.,

```
const handleChange = e => /* set state here */

<input id="editCourse_placeHolder_courseName" type="text" 
    placeholder={edit_Course?.name} onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

When you implement the `onChange` handler, each keystroke will update state. Then, I would validate in the body of the component, e.g.,

```
const isValid = validateForm()
```

You don't need to maintain the valid status in state. You care if it's valid each render so you can allow a form submit, so just do it in the body of the component. Set the result of the validation to the disabled prop on your button.

```
<input name="view" disabled={!isValid} type="submit" 
    onClick={() => {submitEdit();history.push("/");}} value="Edit"
/>
```